# UIAlertView multiple otherButtonTitles enable/disable

Tags: ios, uialertview

I have a `UIAlertView` in my iPhone application, that has two `otherButtonTitles` (login and register)
The AlertView is using the `ViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput`.

What I want to do is, disable both buttons as long as the text fields (username and password) are empty.

I've found a built in method called `alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton` and I managed to implement this.
The problem is, that this method only disables or enables the first other button, and not the second other button (register).

```
- (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView {
    if([[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text] length] > 0 && [[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:1] text] length] > 0) {
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

I have googled for hours but can't find anything about how to enable or disable multiple other buttons in an alertview.

I hope someone on StackOverflow can help me because this is stressing me out.. :(

Comment: There is no public API to do what you want. Your best option is to find and use one of the many custom `UIAlertView` replacements. Find one that allows for what you need. Search github or cocoacontrols for options.

Comment: Thanks for your answer rmaddy. I find it kinda strange that a UIAlertView allows you to have multiple buttons, but that there's only a method to enable or disable the first button. I will have a look at some third party alternatives then, thanks again! ~Kevin

Comment: The `UIAlertView` API is a monster anyway. For what it's worth, I'm planning on implementing a delegate method `alertView:shouldEnableButtonAtIndex:` on `SDCAlertView` (http://github.com/Scott90/SDCAlertView) in the future, but rmaddy is right in that there's currently no API available for it.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thanks for your answer! I'm really looking forward to using your SDCAlertView. :-)